# django force query aliases

Tags: json, django, oracle, django-models

I am writing a custom Oracle `json` field for `Django`, and for it to work the backend *Requires* table names to be aliased. i.e.

This will work:

```
select t.col1.x from table_name t where t.col1.y >2
```

This won't:

```
select col1.x from table_name  where col1.y >2
```

Nor will this:

```
select table_name.col1.x from table_name  where table_name.col1.y >2
```

Is there a flag, etc that can be set on the field, or the backend to force tables to be aliased?

My current workaround is to join the table to itself, which then forces an alias, but it's a bit of a hack.

```
class CustomQueryManager(models.Manager):

    def filter_special(self, *args, **kwargs):

        base_q = super().filter(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.filter(id__in=base_q.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Ideally I would just like to use the standard `MyModel.objects.filter` method without having to force a self join, without the custom `filter_special` method on the manager.